# System.StackOverflowException too much recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow

I am doing an Algorithm class and I am building an implementation of [Kosaraju's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm) as part of the homework.

I have several small datasets where the algorithm is returning the correct results and performing fine. However, when I attempt my homework assignment which has 5,105,043 edges and 875,714 nodes in it I am getting a System.StackOverflowException which seems to be because there is too much recursion.

However, this recursion is required to solve the question. So what I am asking is there a way to configure .Net to allow more recursion?

Comment: How deep *is* your recursion at the moment?

Comment: How do I discern that from the exception? Sorry I am not too familiar with debugging this error.

Comment: Can`t you modify your DFS to be iterative?

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe I have processed 7149 nodes in the first pass so hardly scratching the surface unfortunately.

Comment: @dwrd I can modify my Depth First Search to be iterative. Am I not likely to be able to get this to work recursively?

Comment: @baynezy, take a look [here](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/22/increasing-the-size-of-your-stack-net-memory-management-part-3.aspx), but your amount of nodes and adges is really large, I think that iterative way is better for this.

Comment: The thing to remember about recursion is, it's nice in theory, but when it comes to implementing it, practical people try real hard not to and come up with an iterative solution. As soon as it starts getting bit too deep, we run into practical hardware limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what I am asking is there a way to configure .Net to allow more recursion?

The recursion limit is based on the stack size allocated for the current thread.   This can be [changed via editbin /stack](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/22/increasing-the-size-of-your-stack-net-memory-management-part-3.aspx) for the program, or edited for a specific thread upon the thread's construction.

That being said, any [recursive algorithm can be switched to using a stack instead](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/04/Replacing_Recursion_With_a_Stack.aspx).  This would likely prove more maintainable over time, as it would no longer be dependent on having a very large stack to process appropriately.

Comment: I totally appreciate that it is not ideal to be recursing to this degree. I was just trying to follow the idea through the it's conclusion. Your advice on using a thread solved it for me thank you.